# How to hide or disable in-function printed message

Tags: r, printing

Suppose I have a function such as:

```
ff <- function(x) {
  cat(x, "\n")
  x ^ 2
}
```

And run it by:

```
y <- ff(5)
# 5 
y
# [1] 25
```

My question is how to disable or hide the `5` printed from `cat(x, "\n")` such as:

```
y <- ff(5)
y
# [1] 25
```

Comment: you could add a `verbose= T/F` parameter and an `if` block

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use `capture.output` with `invisible`

```
> invisible(capture.output(y <- ff(2)))
> y
[1] 4
```

or `sink`

```
> sink("file")
> y <- ff(2)
> sink()
> y
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 35):

Here's a nice function for suppressing output from `cat()` by Hadley Wickham:

```
quiet <- function(x) { 
  sink(tempfile()) 
  on.exit(sink()) 
  invisible(force(x)) 
}
```

Use it like this:

```
y <- quiet(ff(5))
```

Source: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Suppressing-output-e-g-from-cat-td859876.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: `sink('/dev/null')` maybe slightly preferable work on mac/linux.

Answer (score 8):

You should also check out `purrr::quietly()`.

```r
ff <- function(x) {
  cat(x, "\n")
  x^2
}

purrr::quietly(ff)(7)$result
#> [1] 49
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function `quiet` from [**spsUtil** library](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/spsUtil/html/quiet.html): suppress cat, print, message and warning.