# Force console to discard print

Tags: r, rstudio

Hi im new at R and I use severals fonctions like BatchGetSymbols... The problem is when I use the function it write in the console wich slows my code. Is it possible to discard unwanted "print".... thanks

for (i in 1:nrow(stock_toronto_venture2)){

try(
   {

tickers <- as.character(stock_toronto_venture2[i,1])

ActiveSymbol <- BatchGetSymbols() # cache in tempdir()

Comment: That particular function seems to `cat()` messages as it runs with no way to disable that behavior internally. To hide those message, use the technique here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208564/how-to-hide-or-disable-in-function-printed-message-in-r/34208658

Comment: Working Thanks :D