# How to define a variable to record the number of processed rows when using R, dplyr and rowwise?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, count, rowwise

I have a function which needs a long time to run. So, I want to know how many rows of my data frame are processed. Usually, we can define a variable in for loop to deal with this easily. But I do not know how to do it in dplyr.

Let's say the code is:

```
library(tidyverse)

myFUN <-functin (x) {
  x + 1
}

a <- tibble(id=c(1:3),x=c(3,5,1))

a1 <- a %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(y=myFUN(x))
```

I hope in somewhere the code, I can define a variable i. The value will be plus 1 every time one row is processed, then print its values in console like:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: As per past comments, when asking questions, we would rather they were written in a technical and neutral style. Chatty material that begs, pleads and implores readers for an answer may be thought of as somewhat coercive, and is not really appropriate for the volunteer audience. Please keep it succinct. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you pass another variable to the function which would be the row number of the dataframe and print it in the function. Something like :

```
myFUN <-function (x, y) {
   message(y)
   x + 1
}
```

and then use

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%  mutate(y = purrr::map2_dbl(x, row_number(), myFUN))

#1 
#2 
#3 
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     id     x     y
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     3     4
#2     2     5     6
#3     3     1     2
```

If your function is vectorized, you can let go `map_dbl` and do

```
a %>% mutate(y= myFUN(x, seq_len(n())))
```

Comment: Good answer---much easier to modify the user function to do this than to try to mess with `dplyr` internals. I would suggest `message` rather than `cat`.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks, updated the answer :) . Is there any advantage/disadvantage of using `message` over `cat` ?

Comment: Using `message` makes it easy to disable. If you're in a situation where you *don't* want the messages, wrap it in `suppressMessages`, or `purrr::quietly` will capture the messages separately. In an Rmd, you can set chunk option `message = FALSE`. If you use `cat`, you have less flexibility, and disabling print statements using `cat` [takes more work/less efficient workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34208564/903061). There's a more complete treatment at [Why is message() a better choice than print() in R for writing a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36700294/903061).