# R: bayesx; Note: created new output directory

Tags: r

I am working on a project where we generate some data and than be make some experiments on it. I am calling bayesx function like this:

```
fit.bayesx <- bayesx(formula = y1 ~ sprem1 + sprem2 + sprem3 + sprem4 + sprem5, data = df,
                     family = "gaussian", method = "MCMC")
```

This function in called in a for loop, apx. 5000-times. Whenever it is called, I get an output on the terminal:

```
Note: created new output directory 'C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUdwqta/bayesx*'!
```

This is really annoying. I also tried:

```
bayesx.control(verbose = TRUE)
```

But it doesn't help. Does anyone know the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to suppress the message or to avoid creating a new directory?

Comment: To avoid creating a new directory would be perfect. If it is not possible, avoiding the message is ok.

Answer (score 1):

To suppress messages from R functions we can use

```
suppressMessages()
```

According to the [R2bayses docu](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R2BayesX/versions/1.1-1/topics/bayesx)  and [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R2BayesX/versions/1.1-1/topics/bayesx.control) we should be able to pass the `outfile` parameter to specify the directory for `bayesx` outfiles.

P.S. please try to always include the necessary packages in your post ;)

Comment: I tried: suppressMessages(fit.bayesx <- bayesx(formula = y1 ~ sprem1 + sprem2 + sprem3 + sprem4 + sprem5, data = df,
                         family = "gaussian", method = "MCMC")) and I still get notes. Also, I tried bayesx(formula = y1 ~ sprem1 + sprem2 + sprem3 + sprem4 + sprem5, data = df,
                         family = "gaussian", method = "MCMC", outfile = "C:/Users/.../Desktop/Bayes/temp"). Still notes.

Comment: If ever it should be: `fit.bayesx <- suppressMessages(bayesx(formula = y1 ~ sprem1 + sprem2 + sprem3 + sprem4 + sprem5, data = df, family = "gaussian", method = "MCMC")) `... When you used the `outfile` param, what output directory did the note say was created?

Comment: I also tried that, still messages. Now created files ares like this: 'C:/Users/.../Desktop/Bayes/temp*', where * means counter in iteration.

Comment: I can only go by the [R2bayesx docu](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R2BayesX/versions/1.1-1/topics/bayesx.control)... a combiation of `outfile` and `verbose=FALSE` ???

Comment: verbose=FALSE does not help. Still messages.

Comment: I've found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208564/how-to-hide-or-disable-in-function-printed-message. I just put the whole line in capture.output(). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution here: [How to hide or disable in-function printed message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208564/how-to-hide-or-disable-in-function-printed-message)

```
capture.output(
  fit.bayesx <- bayesx(formula = y1 ~ sprem1 + sprem2 + sprem3 + sprem4 + sprem5, data = df,
                     family = "gaussian", method = "MCMC", outfile = "C:/Users/.../Desktop/Bayes/temp/."))
```

The output is gone, but new directories are still created.