# How to mask "new prediction" in R

Tags: r, regression

I need to use the predict function in a loop in R, but i don't want to see "new prediction" for each i in this loop, for example:

```
for(i in 1:n)
{
 predictions[i] <- predict(model, newdata = X[i,])
}
```

if n = 10, we have the output:

```
new prediction
new prediction
new prediction
new prediction
new prediction
new prediction
new prediction
new prediction
new prediction
new prediction
```

the predictions are save in predictions vector, but i want a more clean output.

Comment: Why do you use a loop? `predict()` can compute all predictions directly for all rows.

Comment: This is a minimal example, in my original code i need to compute the peña's measure, for this, i have to compute the diference between, all the fitted values of a model, and the predicted values for the i-th case of the model fitted without each case.

Comment: I will update my question with my original code!

Comment: @Duck is right if X is fixed (i.e., `X[(i+1), ]` doesn't depend on the prediction made from `X[i,]`.  Without seeing the rest of the code we don't now.  That said, there is a function in the `ddpcr` package called `quiet()` that claims to stop printing of all output), so `quiet(predictions[i] <- predict(model, newdata = X[i,]), all=TRUE)`, should do the trick.

Comment: Guys i found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208564/how-to-hide-or-disable-in-function-printed-message