# R equivalent of Stata `quietly` command

Tags: r, stata

I am working with an estimation package in R that prints intermediates steps in the console. I want to hide them for the ease of the parsimonious of my output. I came across the `invisible()` function, but apparently, I am missing something.

In Stata, you can invoke `quietly` to prevent functions from displaying anything on the console. The following code illustrates the stated behavior preventing it from printing the output of linear regression estimates.

```
clear all
set obs 100
gen x1 = rnormal()
gen x2 = rnormal()
gen y = 1 + 0.5 * x1 + 1.5 *x2 + rnormal()

*OLS estimates
reg y x1 x2 

# Source   |       SS           df       MS          Number of obs   =       100
# ---------+--------------------------------------   F(2, 97)        =     94.04
# Model    |  254.422382         2  127.211191       Prob > F        =    0.0000
# Residual |  131.217669        97  1.35275947       R-squared       =    0.6597
# ---------+--------------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.6527
# Total    |  385.640051        99  3.89535405       Root MSE        =    1.1631
# 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# y        |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
# -------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
# x1       |   .4309585   .1216285     3.54   0.001     .1895596    .6723573
# x2       |   1.563406    .120716    12.95   0.000     1.323818    1.802994
# _cons    |   .9115768    .118008     7.72   0.000     .6773635    1.14579
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


*Not displaying output on the console; results still on memory. 
quietly reg y x1 x2
```

Direct comparison with R's `lm()` is nonsense because it does not print anything in the console, but for illustration, consider the following `foo()` function.

```
foo <- function(x)
{
  print("x is doubled")
  x <- x * 2
  return(x)
}

invisible( x <- foo(2))
## [1] "x is doubled"

x
## [1] 4
```

I want to hide the message `"x is doubled"` from displaying in the console. Thanks.

Comment: Try `invisible(capture.output(x <- foo(2)))`. See also [How to hide or disable in-function printed message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208564/how-to-hide-or-disable-in-function-printed-message)

Comment: Thank you @IanCampbell that worked perfectly.