# Hiding messages from left_join within purrr::reduce

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following dummy data:

```
start_df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("A","B","C","D")
)

test_df_1 <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("A","B","C","D"),
  col2 = c("test1","test2","test3","test4"),
  val1 = c(1,2,3,4)
)

test_df_2 <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("A","B","C","D"),
  val2 = c(10, 100, 1000, 10000)
)

test_df_3 <- data.frame(
  col2 = c("test1","test2","test3","test4"),
  val3 = c("Yes","No","No","Yes")
)

df_list <- list(
  test_df_1,
  test_df_2,
  test_df_3
)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

test <- start_df %>%
  reduce(df_list, left_join, .init = .) %>%
  filter(val2 < 10000)
```

I want to suppress the merging messages from `left_join` here, but I cannot seem to find a solution as to how that is done. So far all the suggested solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208564/how-to-hide-or-disable-in-function-printed-message), do not seem to work with `reduce`, as far as I know. Also, several of them prevents me from running filtering steps after the merge, such as:

```
test <- start_df %>%
  suppressMessages(reduce(df_list, left_join, .init = .)) %>%
  filter(val2 < 10000)

Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = val2 < 10000`.
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_filter()`:
! object 'val2' not found
```

Any solutions for this?

Comment: @benson23 that worked! Simple fix, thanks! Feel free to add it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `suppressMessages` to include the `data` argument so that it is a valid expression of `suppressMessages`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

test <- suppressMessages(start_df %>% reduce(df_list, left_join, .init = .)) %>% 
  filter(val2 < 10000)
```